# PHP table with subtotal row within a loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a row in table within an array that will have a subtotal row within the loop in addition to the individual rows.

Data:

```
symbol => AAA, quantity => 100
symbol => AAA, quantity => 50
symbol => AAA, quantity => 20
symbol => BBB, quantity => 100
symbol => BBB, quantity => 10
```

My code:

```
echo "<table>\n";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE account_id = '$account_id' ORDER BY symbol ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$numofrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

for($i = 0; $i < $numofrows; $i++) {
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

echo "<tr>\n";

echo "<td>".$row['symbol']."</td><td>".$row['quantity']."</td>\n";

echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

What I want my output to be:

```
<table>
<tr>//subtotal row
<td>AAA</td>
<td>170</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>AAA</td>
<td>100</td>
</tr>    
<tr>
<td>AAA</td>
<td>50</td>
</tr>    
<tr>
<td>AAA</td>
<td>20</td>
</tr>    
<tr>
<td>BBB</td>//subtotal row
<td>110</td>
</tr>    
<tr>
<td>BBB</td>
<td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>BBB</td>
<td>10</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am guessing you are having an issue because of your ending `</table>`.  I probably should ask, what are the results you have now?

Comment: Do you want the sub total row to show up before the individual rows? Because that is how you have it marked in your expected output. Usually totals appear at the bottom of a group.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn yes. sounds weird but I want them at the top

Comment: Then you would need to loop over the data once to get a total for each symbol and then loop over again to add each individual row. At least that is the easiest way. I'll write up an answer that does it as simple as possible but gauging on the code above, this will be a little more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here. This would do what you want. I commented as much as possible.

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM transactions WHERE account_id = '$account_id' ORDER BY symbol ASC";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$numofrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);

//temp data store for the table
$tmp = array();
//temp data store for the totals
$totals = array();
//temp data store for the totals
$costs = array();


for($i = 0; $i < $numofrows; $i++) {
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    //store in variables
    $sym = $row['symbol'];
    $qty = $row['quantity'];
    $cost = $row['cost'] * $qty;

    //if we don't have symbol under our temp store, add it
    if(!isset($tmp[$sym])){
        //add a blank string to the temp store under the symbol
        $tmp[$sym] = '';
        //start our total at 0 for this symbol
        $totals[$sym] = 0;
        //start costs variable at 0 fo rhtis symbol
        $costs[$sym] = 0;
    }

    //add the row under the table for this symbol
    $tmp[$sym] .= "<tr><td>{$sym}</td><td>{$qty}</td><td>{$cost}</td></tr>";

    //add the quantity under the symbol
    $totals[$sym] += $qty;
}

echo "<table>\n";

//second loop to do the output
foreach($totals as $sym=>$total){
    //get the total cost
    $cost = $costs[$sym];
    //echo out the subtotal row
    echo "<tr class='subtotal'><td>{$sym}</td><td>{$total}</td><td>{$cost}</td></tr>";
    //echo out the individual rows
    echo $tmp[$sym];
}

echo "</table>\n";
```

Comment: works perfect! is there a way to add a third variable as "cost" from the sql table and then show the output of cost * quantity in the individual rows and then also show that total of all the rows in the subtotal row?

Comment: There, that should do it.

Comment: Apparently I did miss the `$costs +=...` line. Glad it's working.